# Cancel a stored procedure called from Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an application  that triggers multiple jobs to calculate and update sales records in a given date range. Entity framework allows us to call stored procedures by the following code

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters);
```

This allows us to execute procedures. Is there anyway to cancel a long running stored procedure

Comment: Not to call the procedure maybe? Do you mean stop a runing procedure?

Comment: Regardless of Entity Framework, is there even a way to cancel a running process in SQL Server?  I think the problem might be with the existence of "long running jobs" in the first place.  How "long running" are they?  Why do they need to be?  What is the application doing during this time?  I suspect the application should be handling anything "long running" and the database queries should be fairly quick and optimized.

Comment: Here's a link which shows us how to cancel a Stored procedure call using SqlCommands   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 has the [`ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220055%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method that supports use cancellation tokens which can be used to cancel the task in the normal way, e.g.

```
var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'", token.Token);
// you can now use `token.Cancel` to cancel the SP.
t.Wait();
```

(To get this to work I needed to change to use .Net 4.5 or higher).

Comment: Doesn't work. Cancellation tokens won't stop a long-running stored procedure. ExecuteReader hangs in spite of the passed CancellationToken being cancelled.